# Display Binary Tree Recursively

Tags: recursion, assembly, binary-tree, dos, x86-16

I have code that will add nodes to a tree properly in 16 bit Assembler.  I can display any number of left trees up to max without an issue.  Everytime I try to get the right child to print it crashes the system.  I have tried to see what is happening in turbo debugger and assume I am not getting something saved to or popped off the stack properly.

I have run this code through turbo debugger more times than I can remember and not able to see where the issue(s) are.

```
.MODEL small
.STACK 100h

.DATA
menuchoice DB 10, 10, 13, 'Please enter your choice from the menu. $'

message DB 10, 10, 13, 'Please enter the character you would like to add (enter # to exit): $'

menu    DB 10, 10, 13, 'Binary Search Tree Menu'
        DB 10, 10, 13, '1 - Add a character to the tree'
        DB 10, 10, 13, '2 - Search the tree for a character'
        DB 10, 10, 13, '3 - Display the contents of the tree'
        DB 10, 10, 13, '4 - Exit the program $'

empty   DB 10, 10, 13, '     The tree is empty. $'

crlf    DB 10, 13, '     $'

bintree DB 60 DUP(0) ; create a list with a size of 20 characters

node    DB 0 ; node starts at zero become 1 once value is added
root    DB 1 ; next available slot
next    DB 1 ; next is the pointer to the next slot for the character


.CODE
tree PROC
     ; first two lines in main in all assembler 
       mov ax, @data
       mov ds, ax

DISPLAYMENU: ; set up my label

     ; display menu
       mov dx, OFFSET menu
       mov ah, 09h
       int 21h

     ; display menu choice prompt
       mov dx, OFFSET menuchoice
       mov ah, 09h
       int 21h

     ; get the character from the keyboard with echo
       mov ah, 01h
       int 21h

MAINLOOP: ; set up my label

     ; compare data entry to 4 to exit program
       cmp al, 34h
       je exitprog

     ; compare data entry to 1 to add node
       cmp al, 31h
       je starttree

     ; set root to 1
       mov root, 1

     ; determine if tree is empty, if empty display message
       cmp node, 0
       je emptymessage

     ; compare data entry to 2 to search tree
       cmp al, 32h
       jne check3
       call searchtree

CHECK3: ; set up my label

     ; compare date entry to 3 to display data
       cmp al, 33h
       jne mainloop
       call disptree

       jmp mainloop

     ; set si to zero to represent empty
     ;  mov si, 0

     ; set di to zero to represent empty
     ;  mov di, 0

EXITPROG: ; set up my label       

     ; exit to DOS
       mov al, 0
       mov ah, 04ch
       int 21h

EMPTYMESSAGE: ; set up my label

     ; display empty message
       mov dx, OFFSET empty
       mov ah, 09h
       int 21h

     ; move back to main
       jmp displaymenu

STARTTREE:  ; set up my label

     ; display message
       mov dx, OFFSET message
       mov ah, 09h
       int 21h

     ; get character from keyboard with echo
       mov ah, 01h
       int 21h

       mov ah, 0

     ; check to see if the character entered is #
       cmp al, 23h

     ; if equal jump to exit program
       je exitprog

       mov root, 1

     ; compare next to 60 to determine if there is still space in the tree if not exit
       cmp next, 60
       jnl exitprog

CHECKTREE: ; set up my label

     ; check to see if tree is empty and jump to addnode if equal
       cmp node, 0
       je addnode

     ; compare root to zero and jump to addnode if equal
       cmp root, 0
       je addnode

     ; if not equal then jump to evaltree
       jne evaltree

ADDNODE: ; set up my label

     ; change node value to 1
       mov node, 1

     ; move the array position value in next to si
       mov bl, next
       mov bh, 0
       mov si, bx

     ; move the value into tree
       mov [bintree + si], al

     ; increment next by 3 to move position to next character slot
       add next, 3

     ; jump back to menu
       jmp displaymenu

EVALTREE: ; set up my label

     ; move root to di to compare position
       mov bl, root
       mov bh, 0
       mov di, bx

     ; compare bintree to value
       cmp al, [bintree + di]

     ; if less than jump to left child
       jl leftchild

     ; if greater than jump to right child
       jg rightchild

LEFTCHILD: ; set up my label

     ; subtract 1 from di
       sub di, 1

     ; move the position in bintree + di to root
       mov bl, [bintree + di]
       mov root, bl

     ; compare root to zero and if equal jump to change pointer and not equal to checktree
       cmp root, 0

       je changeptr

       jne checktree

RIGHTCHILD: ; set up my label

     ; add 1 from di
       add di, 1

     ; move the position in bintree + di to root
       mov bl, [bintree + di]
       mov root, bl

     ; compare root to zero and if equal jump to change pointer and not equal to checktree
       cmp root, 0

       je changeptr

       jne checktree

CHANGEPTR: ; set up my label

     ; move next to bintree + di
       mov bl, next
       mov [bintree + di], bl

     ; jump to checktree
       jmp checktree

tree ENDP

searchtree PROC

searchtree ENDP

disptree PROC

     ; save the value in root to the stack
       mov bl, root
       mov bh, 0
       push bx

     ; mov value in root to si
       mov si, bx

     ; decrement si to check the left child of character
       sub si, 1

     ; compare the value in bintree to 0
       cmp [bintree + si], 0
       je ldispret

     ; move the value in bintree + si to root
       mov bl, [bintree + si]
       mov root, bl

     ; return to disptree
       call disptree

     ; get root value from the stack
       mov root, bl

     ; move root to si
       mov bl, root
       mov bh, 0

DISPRIGHT: ; set up my label

       mov si, bx

     ; display the character
       mov dl, [bintree + si]
       mov ah, 02h
       int 21h

     ; increment si to check the right child of the character
       add si, 1

     ; compare the value in bintree + si to 0
       cmp [bintree + si], 0
       jne goright
       jmp rdispret

GORIGHT: ; set up my label

     ; move the value in bintree + si to root
       mov bl, [bintree + si]
       mov root, bl

     ; go back to disptree
       call disptree

ldispret: ; set up my label
     pop bx
     pop ax
     push bx
     push ax
     ret

rdispret: ; set up my label
     ; mov cl, root
     ; add cl, 3
     ; cmp next, cl
     ;je tomain 

     pop bx
     pop bx 

     jmp dispright

     pop bx
     pop bx
     ret

disptree ENDP 

TOMAIN: ; set up my label

     ;jmp mainloop

       end tree
```

When it displays the contents of the binary tree it should print the characters in alphabetical order.  If my input is *m, b, a, c* it should display *abcm* and then return to the menu.  The program crashes when it evaluates the right tree and tries to display it.

Comment: When you have run it in turbo debugger, have you single stepped the code? Did you spot where exactly it goes wrong? Each instruction is just a small unit of work that you have written with a specific behavior in mind. Use the debugger to verify that is indeed what is happening. It should be easy to spot a deviation. PS: if you see your question has bad formatting use the [edit link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55330006/edit) and fix it yourself. Use the code button on the toolbar.

Comment: I have stepped through the code.  It will display any left child properly.  I believe it has to do with the either the positions in the array not being compared properly or not having the values on the stack properly.  It doesn't compare properly to get to the label rdispret, which is designed to manipulate the stack.  The other issue that occurs is if I put in the root node and then a right child it doesn't have enough on the stack to manipulate

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't easy to follow your program flow but I think I managed to find a number of (important) reasons why the code crashes.

> ```
> ; return to disptree
>   call disptree
> ; get root value from the stack
>   mov root, bl
> ```

The *disptree* procedure leaves a word on the stack using the stackmanipulation in *ldispret:*, **but** contrary to your comment above, you don't get anything off the stack! Use `pop bx` `mov root, bl`.

Please note that the first call to *disptree* (the one that comes from the menu) will also have to discard this word from the stack.

---

> ```
> rdispret: ; set up my label
>   pop bx
>   pop bx 
>   jmp dispright
> ```

and

> ```
> DISPRIGHT: ; set up my label
>   mov si, bx
>   ; display the character
>   mov dl, [bintree + si]
> ```

The *rdispret:* code first pops a *root* value and then pops a **return address**. It's the return address that you then mistakenly use as an index in the *bintree* array. Use `pop bx` `pop ax` `jmp dispright`.

---

For any program that uses recursion it is best to allocate a big stack. 256 bytes is a bit cheap.

---

> ```
> CHECK3: ; set up my label
>   ; compare date entry to 3 to display data
>   cmp al, 33h
>   jne mainloop
> ```

Your program enters an endless loop if the user fails to type in a number in the range "1" to "4".

If this happens you need to ask for another character from the user. Move the *mainloop* label 2 lines higher up.

Comment: Thanks.  I will check that out and see how it works.  I appreciate it.